# difference between c# and java write()

Tags: c#, java, serial-port

I am trying to establish serialport communication between my EFTPOS terminal which is connected to serialport and my computer. The EFTPOS manual has a C# code for testing and in that they have the following lines to write to the port and read from the port straightaway.

`port.WriteLine("@PL");

Console.WriteLine(port.ReadLine());`

But in java if i use that my application goes into halt. So i am using eventhandlers in java to read the response from the EFTPOS terminal. Still i couldnot get it work. Now i have a doubt with the WriteLine("@PL") of C# and OutputStream.write(bytearray) of java. Are these 2 methods phrases the string in the same whay when it is written on the port ?? Because the EFTPOS will respond only if the message is "@PL". A solution to this problem will be a great relief for me..

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the Java code, including setting up the port.

Comment: @joev: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830177/problem-writing-to-serialport-in-java i have asked the question with code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that they're writing in different encodings. If the EFTPOS terminal is expecting ASCII and Java is writing UTF-16, it won't work.

Comment: The serial protocol used to communicate with the terminal is a plain-text ASCII protocol based on request and response messages. so what do i have to do to set ASCII format while writing to the port in Java.. ?

Comment: Well Java's OutputStream writes bytes, so are you using `String.getBytes` to convert? You can specify an encoding by using `String.getBytes("US-ASCII")`, for example.

Comment: i have a doubt even if it is writing to the port. is there a way to find tat out ?

Comment: I'm not sure - I think you'd have to use an external program to see.